# Is there a way to specify firefox's executable path in nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, selenium, firefox, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatch to run tests on both Chrome and Firefox.

Everything works like a charm on Chrome. I successfully run tests on Firefox on our servers, but I have an issue on my machine.

For the moment, as Marionnette is not very stable, we're testing our software with **Firefox ESR** which is supported without any driver by selenium.

On my linux machine, I installed both Firefox (latest) and Firefox (Extended Support Release).

- Firefox is accssible in `/usr/bin/firefox`
- Firefox ESR is in `/usr/bin/firefox-es`

With protractor, I can specify which executable to trigger with a magic property named `firefox_path`.

But I have not found how to make **nightwatch** use `/usr/bin/firefox-esr`

Any idea?

My config, if you're interested:

```js
const seleniumPath = /*computed value*/;
module.exports = {
  "src_folders": ["test/e2e"],
  "output_folder": "reports/e2e",
  "detailed_output": false,
  "selenium": {
    "start_process": true,
    "server_path": seleniumPath,
    "log_path": "",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": 4444,
    "cli_args": {},
  },
  "test_settings": {
    "default": {
      "launch_url": launchUrl,
      "exclude": ["utils/**/*", "gulpfile.js", "nightwatch*.js"],
      "selenium_port": 4444,
      "selenium_host": "localhost",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots": {
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "reports/e2e/screenshots",
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "firefox",
        "javascriptEnabled": true,
        "acceptSslCerts": true,
      },
    },
    "test_runner": {
      "type": "mocha",
      "options": {
        "ui": "bdd",
        "reporter": "spec",
      },
    },
  }
```

Comment: you may have luck setting `selenium.start_process` to `true`, and let nightwatch decide how to run.

Answer (score 1):

try this solution and let me know if it is working on your side

```
    selenium: {
     cli_args: {
      'webdriver.gecko.driver': '/path/to/geckodriver'
    }
  },

    test_settings: {
      default: {
        desiredCapabilities: {
          browserName: 'firefox',
          marionette: true,
          javascriptEnabled: true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't want to use the gecko driver. I'm using an old version of Firefox which is still supported and does not need the gecko driver. Testing against this version works, because that's the version we're using on our Jenkins slaves.

Comment: @ghusse - how do you expect to run selenium tests (which nightwatch does, under the hood) without using a web-driver?

Comment: Firefox version ESR does not need a web driver : selenium supports it natively.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have multiple Firefox installs to try, but I would expect `cli_args` to take a property of `webdriver.firefox.binary` containing the path.

This would be in keeping with the other [Selenium Settings](http://nightwatchjs.org/gettingstarted#selenium-settings). Certainly it exists as a setting in the [Firefox section](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#webdriver) in the webdriver docs, and the same capability is there in the [GeckoDriver docs](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver#firefox-capabilities) (although I appreciate you're not using that).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work.